# How to dual boot Lubuntu alongside Tails OS on a pendrive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu, live-usb

I have Tails OS in my 16 GB pendrive. I added it using Rufus and run live. It consumes around 8GB and I created another partition of remaining space inside Tails, it’s around 6GB. How can I install Lubuntu in it and dual boot? Which is better in this space condition: installed Lubuntu or live-run Lubuntu?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which release of Lubuntu, however I've used Lubuntu ISOs using the `ubiquity` installer to install to thumb-drives, you can just `dd` the ISO to the thumb-drive partition you created too though I would then use the tails grub to boot it (as the `dd` won't make it bootable). There are many ways but they'll vary on release (ie. I've not tried installing Lubuntu to thumb-drive using the *di* installer, and had issues with `calamares`, the installer is selected by release & ISO used which you didn't specify).

Comment: @guiverc iam trying to download the latest 64 bit version of lubuntu from the lubuntu site but iam getting this errror message "The requested URL was not found on this server." 32 bit version is working and i think it is lubuntu 18.04. is there any other way to download 64bit version like torrent or something

Comment: Your error is most likely because you weren't using the Lubuntu web site (https://lubuntu.me/).  If you're unsure of the web site, don't ask google (unless you know which answer is correct), ask Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) as Canonical will ensure ubuntu.com sends you to the correct site (google doesn't! they list legitimate, *fan* & fake sites letting the user decide)

Comment: Is your Tails booted using grub? If so you can boot a Lubuntu ISO file by adding a menuentry to grub. you can then add a persistence file or partition, but 6GB is cramped for using persistence.

Comment: @guiverc thanks. you are right. i searched google and they gave me "lubuntu.net". i thought its official site. now i got lubuntu 20.04lts. how can i add it to this thumb drive for dual boot. i want both os live sessions dont want to install

Comment: @C.S.Cameron i think its syslinux. how to do if its syslinux

Comment: In my first comment I listed how I'd do it. I'd just `dd` the ISO to the partition you've created, then assuming your 'tails' already boots, have it provide the option to boot itself OR boot Lubuntu (via `grub`).  You maybe lucky and find `update-grub` would automatically detect the `dd`, but `update-grub` is a Ubuntu command where you'll need to use tails/debian commands

Comment: If Tails was booting with GRUB it would be easy to add Lubuntu. Syslinux is not so easy. UNetbootin can boot multiple OS using Syslinux by installing the OS to different partitions. Unetbootin and most other USB makers do not support Tails. My recommendation is to use Ventoy.

Answer (score 1):

### Ventoy

Ventoy, https://www.ventoy.net/en/isolist.html can be installed to a USB drive in seconds. There are both Windows and Ubuntu versions.

Once installed you only need to drop an ISO file onto the USB and it becomes bootable.

Both Tails and Lubuntu are OS that work as multiboots in Ventoy.

Most Debian based operating systems can also be made persistent.

Answer (score 0):

6GB disk space is too small to install Lubuntu. Get another USB flash drive and run Lubuntu from that. You need a >=4GB USB flash drive to run Lubuntu as a live session.

Comment: is it possible to run both tails and lubuntu from the same usb flash drive

Comment: It is possible to run Lubuntu from a USB drive as a live session without installing it.